# Printf() is less reliable than echo in PHP?

Tags: php, printf, echo

For some reason, I have adopted using `printf($var)` over using `echo $var`. I don't really know why.

However, it seems like if I ever have an issue outputting a string from a variable - if I change `printf($var)` to `echo $var` - 90% of the time it fixes the issue.

This has happened to me on more than one occasion with differing errors, anywhere from **too few arguments** to just echoing a null/blank string.

Can anyone shed some light as to why `printf()` seems to work less reliably than `echo`?

Comment: I assume you're using `printf()` for performance questions :)

Comment: maybe you thought [printf](http://www.php.net/printf) and [echo](http://www.php.net/echo) are equivalent, but theyre very different. youre probably thinking of echo and [print](http://www.php.net/print).

Comment: I'd say the answer to your question depends entirely on your own code. Asking that generally *without* sharing your actual code does not make it a question at all on this website. We could *only guess*.

Comment: So would it be possible to go through my files in Dreamweaver and "Find + Replace" **printf(** with **print(**? I've got no occurances of a 'need' for printf in this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf — Output a formatted string ,print returns a value. It always returns 1.and what the echo do — Output one or more strings

Always returning 1 doesn't seem  useful. And a comma delimited list of arguments can be simulated with  string concatenation or multiple calls

The print function is slightly more dynamic than the echo function by returning a value, and the echo function is slightly (very slightly) faster. The `printf` function inserts dynamic variables/whatever into wherever you want with special delimiters, such as `%s`, or `%d`. For example, `printf('There is a difference between %s and %s', 'good', 'evil')` would return `'There is a difference between good and evil'`.

check this [**PHP: Benchmarking echo vs. print vs. printf**](http://www.nutt.net/2004/12/09/php-benchmarking-echo-vs-print-vs-printf/)

and the result

it appears that echo and print are really, really close in terms of speed. The difference per command was only 2/1,000,000 of a second. It just comes down to personal preference. I use echo because that’s what I used first. The speed drop on print appears to come when you assign a variable, at which point the command speed drops 1/100,000 of a second, which is still fairly minor.

form above link

Comment: All great answers - but because you got a downvote (unneccesarily) I'll accept this one - also for providing that linked article - a good read, thanks!!

Comment: printf doesnt return 1. also, you never addressed why he was experiencing seemingly unreliable behavior from printf. instead, you provided irrelevant info. So...I feel your answer is too far off topic, and thus noise that needs to be downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, don't use `printf($var)` unless you specifically need it.

The reason is that `$var` passed as the first argument is treated as a **format string** and things like `%s` and `%d`, etc. have a **special meaning**. In C / C++ this can cause segmentation faults, whereas in PHP you get a slap on the wrist in comparison.

The equivalent of `echo` or `print` is `printf('%s', $var)`; it casts `$var` to a string and then outputs it.

Btw, `printf()` is a function whereas `echo` and `print` are language constructs; therefore you're likely to get better performance with `echo`.

Comment: If it's just "a slap on the wrist in comparison" why don't use unless needed? Needs elaboration otherwise weird advice (speed aside).

Comment: @bravmech Because using it may lead to **unexpected results**; the principle is the same for both C and PHP, although the immediate effects (potential segfault vs strange result) are different.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is very different from using `echo`, first of all `printf` is a function returning a value while `echo` is what is normally referred to as a "*language construct*".

The first argument to `printf` is supposed to be a *format-string* which is, exactly as the name implies, used to format the outputted string.

`echo` will output the "*parameters*" passed to it as they are (after variable interpolation that is), while `printf` will behave according to the first *format-string*, as mentioned earlier.

For example, try the below snippet and notice some major differences.

```
echo   "I like %s! hello ", "world", " /stackoverflow" ;
echo   "\n"
printf ("I like %s! hello ", "world", " /stackoverflow");
```

<sup>output</sup>

```
I like %s! hello world /stackoverflow
I like world! hello
```

<sup>written and edited using my *BlackBerry*, sorry for any formatting errors..</sup>

Answer (score 0):

echo — Output one or more strings

echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.

printf — Output a formatted string

Returns the length of the outputted string

Comment: http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php